# google apps scriptでカレンダーの「勤務場所」の取得・設定を行いたい

Tags: google-apps-script

GASを使用してGoogleカレンダーの「勤務場所」の取得・設定は可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

APIがまだないようです。
[Goodle Workspace for Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/user-availability/reference/rest/v1alpha/WorkingLocation)によると[デベロッパー プレビュー プログラム](https://developers.google.com/workspace/preview)にて近日公開とのことですので、今は気長に待つしかないですね...